# Render a table, grouped by a specific attribute, in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, grouping

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to render this data structure into an HTML table, grouped by the given attributes:

```js
[
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'tomato', color: 'red', type: 'veggie' },
  { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow', type: 'fruit' },  
]
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>banana</td>
  <td rowspan=2>fruit</td>
  <td rowspan=1>yellow</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>apple</td><td rowspan=2>red</td></tr>
<tr><td>tomato</td><td>veggie</td></tr>
</table>
```

I feel like this is an algorithms problem, but I am having trouble identifying which algorithm is effective in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that spits out a template for how you want each row to look. From there, you can use the [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort them by type (or whichever you choose).

```js
let foods = [
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'tomato', color: 'red', type: 'veggie' },
  { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow', type: 'fruit' },  
];

function addRow(food) {
 return `<tr><td>${food.name}</td><td rowspan=2>${food.color}</td><td rowspan=1>${food.type}</td></tr>`;
}

let sortedFoods = foods.sort((a, b) =>(a.type < b.type) ? -1 : 1);
console.log(sortedFoods);
foods.forEach(food => document.querySelector('.foods').innerHTML += addRow(food));
```

```html
<table class="foods">

</table>
```

Hopefully this helps!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LMulvey/tfgenjm3/)